# How to get rid of "This app isn't verified" warning while using Google OAuth api?

Tags: node.js, api, google-oauth, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google authentication using passport-google-oauth package in node.js .When i try to signup with a gmail account , it says "This App isn't verified." Please see the image.[image]But when i click on "advanced" and then select to proceed anyway,it works fine. In my scope, i have these field

```
 getGoogleLogin: passport.authenticate('google', {
                scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read']
            })
```

Here is what my Google OAuth Consent Screen looks like:[image]

Is there problem with my Verification Status in Google OAuth Consent Screen? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using scopes Google has marked as sensitive. Any use of sensitive scopes will require you to submit your project for review in order to remove the `This app isn't verified` warning.

More information: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

I would also note it seems you are using legacy scopes.
Reference: https://developers.google.com/+/scopes-shutdown

I would try updating these to their newer equivalents:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```